# Can we use StringComparer to sort all kind of strings including special characters?

Tags: c#

I have used `StringComparer.Ordinal` to sort a list of strings. It sorts the strings including special characters except `\\`.
Is there any other options to sort `\\` without writing user defined codes?

Tried the following code:

```
Var string={"#a","\\b","c","1"}
Array.Sort(string,StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

I expect output as

```
#a \\b 1 c
```

but the actual output is

```
#a 1 c \\b
```

Comment: Non-repro. https://www.ideone.com/ak9NR9. Ordinal sorting sorts by Unicode code point, and the output is entirely as expected.

Comment: "but the actual output is" - not the output shown in the question; are you genuinely seeing that? if so, are you on a very exotic runtime? that **is not** the order I see

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile because of multiple issues. Please provide an actual example.

Comment: @mjwills Windows10, framework version 4.7

Answer (score 2):

The code-point of `#` is 35, `1` is 49, `\` is 92, `a`/`b`/`c` is 97/98/99

The output from:

```cs
var arr = new[] { "#a", "\\b", "c", "1" };
Array.Sort(arr, StringComparer.Ordinal);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", arr));
```

is:

```
#a 1 \b c
```

So... it is working as expected, sorting them by their ordinal values.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Is there any way to sort strings like  #a, \\b, 1, c  like special characters are always in first?

Comment: @spc Implement your own [StringComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=netframework-4.8).